# Column selection is set by default in VSCode

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

When selecting text in vscode [os x] it uses column selection, i need to press option while selecting to switch to line selection, how do i reverse this?

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this problem myself. For some reason, the following setting had been turned on:

```json
{
    "editor.columnSelection": false
}
```

There's a key binding called `editor.action.toggleColumnSelection` that toggles it. Accidentally pressing that could have caused this issue.

Comment: saved my day, thank you!